# Exception while extracting XMLType value from Oracle in Java

Tags: java, oracle, sqlxml, xmltype

I am trying to extract XML datatype from Oracle table and facing this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getOracleObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:302) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getSQLXML(NamedTypeAccessor.java:413) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getSQLXML(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1251) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getSQLXML(OracleResultSet.java:488) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
```

Code snippet:

```
SQLXML sqlxml = resultSet.getSQLXML(1);
```

I have double checked the query which is fetching resultset and it is working as expected. Also I am facing this issue only for XMLType column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
        Connection con = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection(); //my oracle connection
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT a.b FROM xml_test a");       
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
           if( rs.getObject(1) != null ){
                 SQLXML xml = rs.getSQLXML(1);
                 System.err.println(xml.getString());
           } else {
                 System.err.println("xmltype is null");
           }                     
        }
        rs.close();
        con.close();        
    }
```

And pom dependency. I recommend to use oracle drivie in 11.2.0.4 version.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: is there any official location to doanload xmlparserv2 jar?

Comment: Official is Oracle XDK. But I have Found this jar in JDeveloper libraries. Or this link can be helpful
[findJar](http://www.findjar.com/jar/mule/dependencies/maven1/oracle-xdb/jars/xmlparserv2.jar.html)

Comment: But you still get java.lang.NullPointerException: null?

Comment: Edit your question and include more java code and sql query

Comment: I was using xmlparserv2 downloaded from findjar. which was an old version. Then I used xmlparserv2 jar from JDeveloper 11.1 generic release downloaded from    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/jdev11122download-1844968.html and it worked. Thanks.